# SharePoint 2010 Source Control

Tags: deployment, source-control

We are making a farm solution in SharePoint 2010 and several developers will work on the site simultaneously.

As per the company norms, whatever we code should go into the sub-version source control server. Since, the changes to lists and pages can be done via:

1. Visual Studio (Sub-version is no issue if all changes are done here)
2. SharePoint Designer
3. Out of the box

Is there any way that I can track all the changes and possibly achieve this?

If it is not possible, then how do we deploy the entire site when the development is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think TFS / Team Foundation Server would be a better solution to track all the changes and versions of the solution that you deploy as farm solutions . and when you have new changes to made for a particular solution then you can map it locally, make changes  store as a new version on TFS with the changes made and deploy the new solution the the farm.

In this way you have the solution and all its updated versions including the sub versions for that projects. For list and pages versions you can activate the versioning settings in SharePoint for that particular list library or pages.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you also please share links that illustrate the procedure or might help in achieving the above.

Answer (score 0):

The changes made in the SP designer can be made as part of the Visual Studio solution. This usually requires extra coding but most of the changes made through designer can be automated through code in the solution. Moreover, the manual changes (OOB changes) can be documented and should be made as part of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you also please share links that illustrate the procedure or might help in achieving the above.